# Page content not visible in backend

Tags: content

I was asked to take a look at a WordPress website. The front page had a lot of content on it, that I wanted to edit, but when I opened up the page editor, there was nothing at all in the content field.

I created an exact copy of the page, and that showed completely blank except for the header and footer (which was at the top of the page).
I suspected the content came from the WPBakery Page Builder plugin which was installed, but deactivating it made no difference. I also tried deactivating all other plugins one by one, but it made no difference.

Where is this content coming from?

Comment: please check  to console if jquery was error otherwise conflict

Comment: How do I do that? I'm not an experienced developer.

Comment: I figured out what you meant. It only shows two warnings about Google Maps Javascript API. No red line with errors.

Comment: can you please share your site link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is most likely coming from a template file. Look inside your theme folder for files such as `front-page.php`, `page-home.php`, `content-home.php`, etc...

Comment: I'm using a child theme, and switching to the parent theme seems to resolve this. So I guess all that content is coded directly into the child theme's template files. I wonder why it was done that way. I'll have a look at it.